# Whether there is a jQuery plugins that can screenshot one frame in video that user upload? or some methods?

Tags: javascript, jquery

when user see videos,we should put one preview picture to see,just like the preview picture at youtube,how can i screenshot one frame in a video by some jquery plugins or html5?

Comment: This is not a programming question and thus is off topic for SO. Please take a look at [su] or [webapps.se]

Comment: I don't think you will be able to do it on client-side. You probably have to handle the video on the backend to extract a frame. What are you using on the backend?

Comment: i use java on the backend